# open keyboard only when user click into the searchView

Tags: android, json, android-studio, search, searchview

i am making app with my WordPress Website with json , i have added searchView to my MainActivity , all works fine but the only problem is when MainActivity diplay , keyboard of searchView automatically appears and i want it to be displayed when user click into the Search Bar..

this is my code to show searchView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bgcoor"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.punjabidharti.punjabistatus.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:queryHint="Search Status Here"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"


    />

<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/hash"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:text="#Hashtag"
                    android:textSize="30dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

            </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is the code to make it work:

```
addListenerOnButton();

 public void addListenerOnButton() {

        final Context context = this;

  SearchView searchview = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
                        searchview.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener(){

                            @Override
                            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {

                                // some code here


                                return false;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                                return false;
                            }
                        });

}
```

please help..

Comment: `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"` add this to your MainAcitivity in AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: ... and depending on your use-case, you may want to `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"` to allow Android to resize the activity so it's not covered by the keyboard (when in doubt [check the docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#wsoft))

Comment: not works bro :( @Nitish

Comment: `getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN)‌​;` try adding this at run time in onCreate() method, if still not working please update the code for Manifest file 
`

Comment: not works bro :( @Nitish

Comment: You're going to have to provide more information then, this is the correct way to do it, and if the keyboard still pops up, then perhaps share all your layout, and your activity/fragment code.

Comment: please check my updated code @MartinMarconcini

Answer (score 0):

Please just try this way to use below code to hide and show the keyboard when you need, when you first come at activity then hide it.

```
public class KeyboardUtils {

/**
 * this method shows the keyboard on corresponding edittext
 * @param editText
 */
public static void showKeyboard(EditText editText) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) TaxiappApplication.getInstance().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
}

/**
 * this method hides the keyboard on corresponding edittext
 * @param editText
 */
public static void hideKeyboard(EditText editText) {
    try {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) TaxiappApplication.getInstance().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }catch (Exception e){
        ExceptionHandler.printStackTrace(e);
    }
}

/**
 * this method hides the keyboard on current view
 *
 * @param activity
 */
public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {

    try {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        //Find the currently focused view, so we can grab the correct window token from it.
        View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
        //If no view currently has focus, create a new one, just so we can grab a window token from it
        if (view == null) {

            view = new View(activity);

        }
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);

    }catch (Exception e){
        ExceptionHandler.printStackTrace(e);
    }
}


public static boolean isActiveKeyboard(Activity activity){
    return ((InputMethodManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).isActive();
}

/**
 * this method hides the keyboard on view
 * @param activity
 */
public static void hideKeyboardOnview(Activity activity){
    try {
        activity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    }catch (Exception e){
         ExceptionHandler.printStackTrace(e);
    }
}
```

}

Hope it may help you

Comment: android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"

this works for me , Thanks Guys for help